# strtol not working as expected

Tags: c, string, strtol

I am unable to convert a string to a long using strtol. Having a leading `"."` before the number in the string returns 0.
Without the `"."` strtol returns `3456` as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <stdlib.h>   

int main ()
{                                                                   
    char str[20] = " . 3456\r\n";                                                                    

    long ret = strtol(str, NULL, 10);                                            
    printf("ret is %ld\n",ret);

    return(0);                                                                   
}
```

Comment: why do you expect `strtol` to skip the leading point?

Comment: Here is [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)

Comment: @KarstenKoop Ok that is my misunderstanding of the function. Is there a similar function I can use that will fit this use case

Comment: what is the usecase? Do you want a long with the value 3456 or a double with value 0.3456?

Comment: @KarstenKoop A long with 3456. That `.` is not a decimal value it is just a char returned from a sensor so I want to ignore it.

Comment: @homeGrown What do you want to do with minus signs?

Comment: @zwol it doesn't report negative values. I only asked about ignoring the `.`

Comment: @homeGrown But you're using `strtol` and `long` instead of `strtoul` and `unsigned long`, so I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strto*` library functions will only skip over leading whitespace.  If you want to skip over other text, you need to do it by hand.  The `isxxx` functions from `ctype.h` can help with this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *p, *endp;
    unsigned long ret;
    int fail = 1;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s number-to-parse\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }
    p = argv[1];
    while (*p && !isdigit(*p)) p++;

    errno = 0;
    ret = strtoul(p, &endp, 10);     
    if (endp == p)
        printf("'%s': no number found\n", str);
    else if (*endp && !isspace(*endp))
        printf("'%s': junk on line after number\n", str);
    else if (errno)
        printf("'%s': %s\n", str, strerror(errno));
    else {
        printf("'%s': parsed as %lu\n", str, ret);
        fail = 0;
    }
    return fail;
}
```